# SQL - Right join or where exists / where in subquery

Tags: sql, t-sql, join

I've got a table with a schema like:

**tblRecords**:

```
RecordID | ResultID | RecordName
```

another table is **tblResults**:

```
ResultID | ResultTime | Result Date
```

`tblRecords` contains some records with `ResultID` that isn't in `tblResults`.

What I'm trying to do is get all values from `tblRecords` where the `ResultID` is in `tblResults`.

Is that possible with a join?
Or have I got to use a subquery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it can be done.  Try the query below:

```
SELECT tRec.* 
FROM tblRecords tRec
INNER JOIN tblResults tRes
ON tRec.ResultId = tRes.ResultId
```

Comment: Duplicate records would be returned for tblRecords if there are more than one associated record in tblResults.

Comment: But it's `tblRecords` that references `tblResults`, not the other way round. A `tblRecords` row cannot possibly reference more than one `tblResults` row, and therefore there can't be any duplicates. That is to say, I conclude that at most one row  can be referenced because `tblResults.ResultID` is most likely the primary key (and so there can't be more than one row with the same `ResultID` in `tblResults`).

Comment: Ahh I see what you are saying.  Assuming that `tblResults.ResultID` is the PK (and I think it is) you are right.  Updated my answer to reflect this.  The fact that `tblRecords` can have a `ResultId` that doesn't exist in `tblResults` suggests he has junk data, but that's a whole different question.

Answer (score 1):

> get all values from tblRecords where the ResultID is in tblResults

Then try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblRecords
WHERE ResultID IN (SELECT DISTINCT ResultID FROM tblResults)
```

Comment: If a table has huge number of records, using IN can slow down performance.

Comment: @MuhammadGhazi - Not in SQL Server. This is more efficient than doing a join and eliminating the duplicates with distinct. The `DISTINCT` in the sub query is unnecessary though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use a table join.

```
tblRecords.RecordID = tblResults.ResultID
```